# Download a PDF from JS generated links

Tags: download, casperjs, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I'm trying to download PDF's from a site. The links are being generated by JS and I'm able to collect the URL's. How do I tell my headless browser to *click* on these links and download the file(s) ?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links;
var fs = require('fs');

function getLinks() {
  links = document.querySelectorAll('.skb-dabslink a');

  return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
    return e.getAttribute('href')
  });
}

casper.start('https://www.skybriefing.com/portal/dabs');

casper.wait(5000) ; //Waiting for the links to display

casper.then(function () {
  links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.then(function () {
  for(var i in links) {
    console.log(links[i]);
  }
});

casper.then(function () {
  console.log(fs) ;
  fs.write("links.txt", links, 'w');
})

casper.run()
```